# A verb for dividing a system into stages or levels?

Tags: word-request, verbs

Is there a verb with a meaning close to "split" or "break", but for layers or a hierarchy? As in "making a system/team/... layered"?

For example:

> If we ________ the tech team, their performance will deteriorate.
>
> The system is ___________ and the changes propagate from the top level to the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the verb "layer." One meaning of the transitive form of that verb is:

> form or arrange in layers

So

> The system is layered, and consequently changes will propagate from top to bottom.

It does not work quite as well for your first example because "team" has the connotation of a unity.

> If we layer tech teams, their performance will be poorer than that of a single integrated team.

Answer (score 1):

The verb "stratify" would seem to work well.

Stratify: to arrange in a hierarchical order, especially according to graded status levels.

> If we statify the tech team, their performance will deteriorate.
>
> The system is stratified and the changes propagate from the top level to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

A rarely-seen word, [*hierarchize*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hierarchize), is perhaps the closest match... but you might find objections to it as being unusual (though it's been used since at least 1884).

Other choices, such as [*ranking*](https://www.freethesaurus.com/hierarchize), might be better.

The second example calls for an adjective, and *hierarchical* **is** in common use... but a mouthful.